# How can I determine a funtion has the form y = k/x so that there is a square lies on graph?

Tags: equation-solving, graphics

I am trying to find the integer number `k` of the function `y = k/x` so that on the graph of the function  `y = k/x` there is a square `ABCD` which coordinates of four points are integer numbers. I tried

```
f[x_] = k/x
aa = {a, f[a]};
bb = {b, f[b]};
cc = {-a, -f[a]};
dd = {-b, -f[b]};
Solve[{VectorAngle[bb - aa, bb - cc] == Pi/2, 
  VectorAngle[aa - bb, aa - dd] == Pi/2, 
  VectorAngle[cc - bb, cc - dd] == Pi/2, 
  EuclideanDistance[aa, bb] == EuclideanDistance[cc, bb], 
  1 <= a <= 20, 1 <= b <= 20, 1 <= k <= 10}, {a, b, c, d, 
  k}, Integers]
```

With this code, I can not get any square. How can I get a square?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Here we try to prove that there no `Reals` solution about the question.( We do not assume that the center of the square is `{0,0}`)
- Assume that the four points on the curve `x*y=k` are `{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3},{x4,y4}`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
cond1 = {x1*y1 == x2*y2, x2*y2 == x3*y3, x3*y3 == x4*y4};
cond2 = {({x1, y1} - {x2, y2}) . ({x2, y2} - {x3, y3}) == 
    0, ({x2, y2} - {x3, y3}) . ({x3, y3} - {x4, y4}) == 
    0, ({x3, y3} - {x4, y4}) . ({x4, y4} - {x1, y1}) == 
    0, ({x4, y4} - {x1, y1}) . ({x1, y1} - {x2, y2}) == 0};
cond3 = {({x1, y1} - {x2, y2}) . ({x1, y1} - {x2, y2}) == ({x3, 
        y3} - {x2, y2}) . ({x3, y3} - {x2, y2}), ({x3, y3} - {x2, 
        y2}) . ({x3, y3} - {x2, y2}) == ({x4, y4} - {x3, y3}) . ({x4, 
        y4} - {x3, y3}), ({x4, y4} - {x3, y3}) . ({x4, y4} - {x3, 
        y3}) == ({x1, y1} - {x4, y4}) . ({x1, y1} - {x4, y4})};
eqns = Flatten@{cond1, cond2, cond3};
gb = GroebnerBasis[
   Subtract @@@ eqns, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4}];
sol = Reduce[gb == 0, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4}];
Reduce[sol && {x1, y1} != {x2, y2} && {x1, y1} != {x3, y3} && {x1, 
    y1} != {x4, y4} && {x2, y2} != {x3, y3} && {x2, y2} != {x4, 
    y4} && {x3, y3} != {x4, y4} && x1*y1 != 0]
```

> `False`.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a comment/question, but requires a figure, so please don't downvote.]

Is this what you're actually seeking?

[image]

Comment: All of the  four points need to on the curve.

Comment: Then impossible.